# Chrome: Cross-origin plugin content from must have a visible size larger than 400 x 300 pixels

Tags: google-chrome

I am using Google Chrome Version 62.0.3202.94 and recently get this new error message in the developer console:

`Cross-origin plugin content from  must have a visible size larger than 400 x 300 pixels, or it will be blocked. Invisible content is always blocked.`

Site: https://www.matheretter.de

Clicking on the error brings me to the first line of the HTML: `<!DOCTYPE html>` which is not helpful to track down the problem.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is likely Flash content being blocked (check the console, it will likely report a URL with an swf file). Google started *de-emphasizing* Flash over a year ago. According to the article and forum thread below, Chrome actually started "*pausing* any cross-origin plugin content smaller than 400px in width or 300px in height" in September 2015, now I suppose it's blocking it altogether:

https://games.slashdot.org/story/16/08/09/211225/google-chrome-53-will-de-emphasize-flash-in-favor-of-html5-next-month

Original forum thread of Chromium developers:

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/chromium-dev/QL2K4yFVg_U/vj44YWOaAwAJ

Comment: Thansk for the hint! The forum says `An icon will be displayed in the URL bar indicating that plugin content is not running`, however, on the site (see question) there is no warning like this. There is also no SWF loaded, even if flash is allowed (that's the weirdest part). As Maciej says, probably an extension.

Comment: Ah, found it, it is an extension! In the console under Network there was a `chromecastcheck.js` - which came from the "Video Downloader professional" extension. I disabled the extension, now the error is gone.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the feedback! Mystery solved : )
So the extension was trying to download some Flash content?

Comment: I guess so. I have just checked the extension folder if it uses a `swf` file itself, but it is not. Folder: `AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\elicpjhcidhpjomhibiffojpinpmmpil\1.98.1_0`

Comment: Well if it's a video downloader maybe it was trying to download a Flash video? ; )

Comment: In my case I deactivated AdBlock and problem solved. Nothing to do with Flash.

Comment: @MaximeFreschard The message is quite clear: "Invisible content is always blocked." If AdBlock was making some content invisible (and that's pretty much what it does), then probably Chrome was blocking it altogether in return. As I mentioned, Flash content is a possible culprit but not necessarily the only option (it could be a simple image, a GIF, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Try in Incognito mode. I had the same issue but the message is not showing in Incognito so I assume it might be caused by some browser extensions.